# How to get the tag to be recognized correctly?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, tags

I want to make a code that does something only if the tag of an object matches the characters of interest. What I did was write this:

```
if str(canvas.gettags(object))=='thistag':
    do_this_thing(object)
else: 
    pass
```

When I run the code, it seem that the tag never matches. So I print the tag in the condition `else` and I get this:
`('thistag',)`.

How should I write the tag so that it can be recognized?

Comment: Have you tried `print(canvas.gettags()` and verifying it is what you want?

Comment: Try `if 'thistag' in canvas.gettags(object)`.  Don't use keyword (`object`) as variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gettags` returns a tuple, so you need to compare it to a tuple or check that your tag is part of the tuple.

```
if (canvas.gettags(object) == ('thistag',)):
    ...
```

... or ...

```
if 'thistag' in canvas.gettags(object):
    ...
```